# How to handle date from multiple select fields in laravel 5.2

Tags: forms, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

Currently i have created a form field like this in laravel 5.2:

```
        <li class="form-input-date">    
            <label>Birthday</label>
            <div id="PersonForm_date_of_birth">
                <div class="style-select">
                    {{ Form::selectRange('day', 1, 31) }}
                </div>

                <div class="style-select">
                    {{ Form::selectMonth('month') }}
                </div>

                <div class="style-select">
                    {{ Form::selectYear('year', 1906, 1996) }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </li>
```

What is the best way to handle this and add the selected data to a single database (date)field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the Carbon library at your disposal. Try something like this:

```
$year = \Request::get("year"); \\format YYYY
$month = \Request::get("month"); \\format MM
$day = \Request::get("day"); \\format DD

$yourModel->yourDate = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromDate($year,$month,$day);
```

Simple as that.